# Symfony data fixtures on ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fixtures

I have two entities **Categories** and **Criteria** that are linked by **ManyToMany** relationship. It generated a new table named as **criteria_categories** in the database.
What i want to do is to use fixture to populate the `entity Criteria` and the table `criteria_categories`.
The `categories table` has already data in the database.

So my problem is, how to get the data from `categories` and insert them using fixtures into the `criteria_categories table`?

My code is as follow:

**Criteria**

```
class Criteria
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categories", inversedBy="criteria", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="criteria_categories")
     **/
    private $categories;
}
```

**Categories**

```
class Categories
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Criteria", mappedBy="categories")
     **/
    private $criteria;
}
```

**DataFixtures**

```
class LoadCriteria extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $criteria = array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Test1'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Test2'
            )
        );
        $cat = new Categories();

        foreach ($criteria as $critere) {
            $ctr = new Criteria();
            $ctr->setCriteriaLabel($critere['label']);
            $manager->persist($ctr);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

}
```

**So the real question is** how to get the data from categories and use them here in this fixture to populate the `table criteria_categories`?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Are you going to use such fixtures for test environment?

Comment: In fact, i will use them to prod if i could manage it successfuly, but now i'm in dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In doctrine you can forget on `criteria_categories` table. The class `criteria` has a collection of `categories`. Don't need to worry about additional tables used behind the scenes.

But to your question. To get all categories from the db, you have to define this fixture as a service and then inject an entity manager or your "wrapper" service.

```
class LoadCriteria extends Fixture
{
    /**
     * @var CategoriesRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->repository = $em->getRepository(Categories::class);

    }
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->categories = $repository->findAll();

        $criteria = array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Test1'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Test2'
            )
        );
        $cat = new Categories();

        foreach ($criteria as $critere) {
            $ctr = new Criteria();
            $ctr->setCriteriaLabel($critere['label']);
            $manager->persist($ctr);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

1. If you use [default service configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-container-services-load-example) from symfony 3.3+, your fixture is already a service.
2. If you don't use default service configuration, you have to define the fixture as service manually by.

   ```
   #services.yml
   App\DataFixtures\ORM\CriteriaFixture:
       tags: [doctrine.fixture.orm]
   ```

Comment: You're welcome :-). Can you than accept this answer?